# python: How do I compare doc A and doc B and if it finds a string that matches in doc B how do I print the entire line?

Tags: python, pandas

I have document A:

```
['5a0cd3b5-4249-bf6f-d009-17a81532660e', '7e44fc1b-44fa-cdda-8491-f8a5bca1cfa3', 'daa73753-4b56-9d21-d73e-f3b3f4c9b1a6', 'f7425a39-43ca-e1fe-5b2b-56a51ed479c5']
```

I have document B:

```
abc 5a0cd3b5-4249-bf6f-d009-17a81532660e
def CDA41B87-4D3A-C17C-5F6D-8990CC9C5EFB
ghi Odin 157BCEBE-484D-82E2-2A60-C8B4B11197EA
jkl 72E724E9-4BA4-2D12-CE1A-8DB1A528B9D3
mno 9E648B20-4ED5-1F34-87A9-979CBE9A958A
```

If the IDs in document A match with IDs from document B, how can you print the entire line?

Exemple: This ID '5a0cd3b5-4249-bf6f-d009-17a81532660e' from doc A is found in doc B at the first line: 'abc 5a0cd3b5-4249-bf6f-d009-17a81532660e'. (print the first line)

I've tried using panda:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('shopid.txt', header=None, names=['id'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('skin_database2.txt', header=None, names=['id', 'name'], delim_whitespace=True)

res = df2[df2['name'].isin(df1['id'].unique())]
print(res)
```

I've also tried this:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    data = response.json()["SkinsPanelLayout"]["SingleItemOffers"]
dataLog = []
with open('skin_database2.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if line.__contains__(data):
        print(line)
        dataLog.append(line)
print(dataLog)
```

But I get this error:

```
    if line.__contains__(data):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

is there a way to use a list/variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inputs:

Shopid.txt:

```
['157BCEBE-484D-82E2-2A60-C8B4B11197EA', '7e44fc1b-44fa-cdda-8491-f8a5bca1cfa3', '65BAA0CD-42EC-F99D-54A0-338D795B5824', 'f7425a39-43ca-e1fe-5b2b-56a51ed479c5']
```

Otherfile.txt:

```
Glitchpop Odin,97AF88E4-4176-9FA3-4A26-57919443DAB7
dot EXE Odin,5A0CD3B5-4249-BF6F-D009-17A81532660E
Prime//2.0 Odin,157BCEBE-484D-82E2-2A60-C8B4B11197EA
Prism III Odin,72E724E9-4BA4-2D12-CE1A-8DB1A528B9D3
Smite Odin,9E648B20-4ED5-1F34-87A9-979CBE9A958A
Sensation Odin,65BAA0CD-42EC-F99D-54A0-338D795B5824
Lightwave Odin,57523CF0-4574-968B-9F17-168E3BDB6D0D
Standard Odin,F7425A39-43CA-E1FE-5B2B-56A51ED479C5
```

- Mention: in order for pandas to read rows correctly, you need to format the inputs as I did. (the shopid.txt must have each entry on separate rows whereas the other must have name and id separated by ,)

Pandas solution revised:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('shopid.txt', 'r') as f:
    in_list_formatted = str(f.read()).replace(
        '[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'', '').split(',')
    inputs = [i.strip().upper() for i in in_list_formatted]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(inputs, columns=['id'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('skin_database2.txt', header=None, names=[
                  'name', 'id'])

found_list = []
for item in df1['id']:
    found = df2.loc[df2['id'] == item]
    if found.empty:
        continue
    found_list.append(found)
output = pd.concat(found_list, ignore_index=True)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
              name                                    id
0  Prime//2.0 Odin  157BCEBE-484D-82E2-2A60-C8B4B11197EA
1   Sensation Odin  65BAA0CD-42EC-F99D-54A0-338D795B5824
2    Standard Odin  F7425A39-43CA-E1FE-5B2B-56A51ED479C5
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work, same error, i'll try with something else.

Comment: @jerf I initially forgot to change one variable. Can you try again now?

Comment: "NameError: name 'data_init' is not defined" Do I need to use a class?

Comment: @jerf make sure you copy the whole code. data_init should be defined in the second line.

Comment: "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list" back to square one.

Comment: @jerf that's very weird as line should be a string. make sure it is "if line in data_init:"

Comment: It's just sending the entire list. It's not actually checking if it matches

Comment: @jerf I will give it a try using pandas.

Comment: @jerf added pandas solution.

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, name]
Index: [] this is what im getting. I'll look into it

Comment: @jerf the input data you gave must be different than the one you used. I noticed an Odin word in doc B

Comment: `Glitchpop Odin 97AF88E4-4176-9FA3-4A26-57919443DAB7
dot EXE Odin CDA41B87-4D3A-C17C-5F6D-8990CC9C5EFB
Prime//2.0 Odin 157BCEBE-484D-82E2-2A60-C8B4B11197EA
Prism III Odin 72E724E9-4BA4-2D12-CE1A-8DB1A528B9D3
Smite Odin 9E648B20-4ED5-1F34-87A9-979CBE9A958A
Sensation Odin 65BAA0CD-42EC-F99D-54A0-338D795B5824
Lightwave Odin 57523CF0-4574-968B-9F17-168E3BDB6D0D
Standard Odin F454EFD1-49CB-372F-7096-D394DF615308`
Here's an actual portion of the skin_database2.txt file
I think the problem is that the "name" is more than just one string and has spaces unlike my example

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to match the ID's and then print the whole line.

Comment: @jerf I can help you better if you add your actual data in the inputs in the question. Also, nicely formatted so I know when a row ends and such.

Comment: Here's also an example of the shopid.txt file that will work :

`['157BCEBE-484D-82E2-2A60-C8B4B11197EA', '7e44fc1b-44fa-cdda-8491-f8a5bca1cfa3', '65BAA0CD-42EC-F99D-54A0-338D795B5824', 'f7425a39-43ca-e1fe-5b2b-56a51ed479c5']`

Comment: On the skin_database2.txt file, the row ends are at the end of the ID's and the new line starts at the name. I can't seem to format it to be able to show the row ends.

Comment: I need it that when it finds a identic ID it prints the name that it corresponding to the ID (which is to the left of it, eg: Glitchpop Odin 97AF88E4-4176-9FA3-4A26-57919443DAB7)

Comment: Works on my end !, but here's the last little problem I believe, I'm quite bad at json/regex. my shopid.txt file is formulated just like I sent, but how do I change in to be in rows just like showed? My shopid.txt is only on one row instead of the 4 that are needed.

Comment: @jerf Should now work on your shopid.txt input.

Comment: @jerf an upvote for the answer would be much appreciated :)